# PDO Collect username or email

Tags: pdo

I would like to know how can I take verify if username or email (Not both because that I managed to do) are already in my db using this code?

```
<?php 

/**
* Register User
*/
if (isset($_POST['register'])) {

$username = $_POST["username"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$salt = "Not important";
$password_hash = crypt($password, "$2y$". $salt);

if (strlen($username) > 20) {
    echo "Username is too big";
}elseif (strlen($password) > 32) {
    echo "Password is too big";
}elseif (strlen($email) > 100) {
    echo "E-Mail is too big";
}else{
    $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT username, email FROM user WHERE username = ? AND email = ?');
    $sth->execute(array($username, $email));
    if ($result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        print $result->username . "Username and email correct";
    }else{
        echo "Username or email incorrect"; //This is where I want to know how can I check one after another?
    }

}
}else{
echo "Not important";
}


?>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to know how can I take verify if *username **or** email*
>
> SELECT username, email FROM user WHERE *username = ? **AND** email = ?'*

Need any further explanations?

Comment: Thank you. Do you think my method of registration is good or bad practice? Thank you again.

Comment: I assume it is not registration but only part that doies check email and login existence? It's quite all right, save for you need to always encode user input when printing it out: `htmlspecialchars(print $result->username)`